# CAN i reinstall the system apps which i have deleteed accidently during rooting?

Tags: system, default-applications

Recently i have rooted my phone .And somehow my media storage has beeen deleted during the rooting process ans i cant play the music and watch photos .My andriod version is 5.1. So can somebody send me the apk file (the apk file of system apps can be created by apk extractor ,you can find it  on play store) of the media storage ,so i can reinstall it.
P.S.I have tried with other versions of andriod and i failed.

PHONE DATAILS:
OBI SJ1.5
RAM 1 GB

Comment: I don't think rooting will delete anything automatically (though depending on the device unlocking your bootloader can sometimes reset your device & delete all files in your internal storage). What device is this? What apk files are you looking for? Did you try [apkmirror.com](https://www.apkmirror.com)?

Comment: i am looking for media storage .This must be the inbuilt  file for photos and music synchronisation.And ,yes i have tried apkmirror.com but unfortunately i can't find for my particular version i.e 5.1

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include what device you're talking about? Apart from that, we don't send files around here. But with enough details provided, we might be able to help you solving your issue.

Comment: System app APKs need to be signed with the same key that was used to sign your system image, so nobody can help unless you say what phone you have.

Answer (score -2):

You might need to reset your phone to stock rom for that

Comment: "Reset" won't restore stuff deleted from the `/system` partition (where pre-installed apps reside). And "might" rarely makes an answer. What steps would you suggest?

Comment: @Izzy resetting to stock rom means reinstalling stock rom on the device

Comment: Not necessarily; installing something is no reset. I read it as "perform a reset to factory settings" (factory-reset). Flashing the stock ROM of course would solve the issue. But then it wouldn't necessarily have to be "stock", as flashing a custom ROM would solve it the same. Maybe you could [edit] your post?

Comment: @Izzy How would flashing a custom rom solve OP's problem when he wants default system apps from the manufacturer?

Comment: OP wants the problem solved. I don't see a statement saying "but please only the apps from this manufacturer". What I'm mainly pointing at is that "reset your phone" is ambiguous, so you should at least make clear what you mean and include some basic pointers on how to do that.

Comment: @Izzy That depends on your terminology. I did not tell OP to perform a reset to factory settings but to reset/to back to an initial state his phone to stock ROM

Comment: I don't think i want to flash a stock/custom rom or factory reset .PLUS my phone is obi SJ 1.5  and custom recovery is nowhere to be found for this phone .I just want to get the manufacturer app (i.e media storage ) so i can listen to my music and watch photos.AND thank you for your precious answers.

Comment: @IronMan you don't have to reinstall system apps for that just download AVG media gallery and VLC and you should be fine

Comment: THANK YOU everyone for your help . I have downloaded the poweramp and quick pic which seems to work fine for me .BUT i have no idea how these twowork without media storage on the device .

Comment: @IronMan Media Storage keeps a database of media in your device. A multimedia app can depend on that solely to list, search and play the files or can have its own database and scanning methods. Probably, the two apps are using the latter approach.